While trying a basic scenario to launch App in IOS real device using Appium with java. Getting below error:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Host info: host: 'deekshasharma-RR9J66KHF6', ip: '2402:e280:217b:120:91ae:ee91:2735:5e9%en0'
Build info: version: '4.25.0', revision: '8a8aea2337'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '14.6.1', java.version: '22.0.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {automationName: XCUITest, bundleId: com.patientsafesolutions.pa..., derivedDataPath: /Users/deekshasharma/Deskto..., deviceName: iPhone15, platformName: IOS, platformVersion: 17.5.1, udid: 00008120-00145D182E10A01E, usePrebuiltWDA: true}]}]
Capabilities {automationName: XCUITest, bundleId: com.patientsafesolutions.pa..., derivedDataPath: /Users/deekshasharma/Deskto..., deviceName: iPhone15, platformName: IOS, platformVersion: 17.5.1, udid: 00008120-00145D182E10A01E, usePrebuiltWDA: true}
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:563)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:270)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:91)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:103)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.(IOSDriver.java:101)
at LaunchIosApp.main(LaunchIosApp.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal key values seen in w3c capabilities: [automationName, bundleId, derivedDataPath, deviceName, platformVersion, udid, usePrebuiltWDA]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.lambda$validate$5(NewSessionPayload.java:163)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$15$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:555)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$15$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:556)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:212)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$15$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:556)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1709)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:556)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:546)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:265)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:611)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.validate(NewSessionPayload.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.(NewSessionPayload.java:70)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:84)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:60)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:176)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:237)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
... 6 more
I am using appium 2.11 version and Java's version is 22.0.1
What should I do. Can anyone help


In your code if you are using appium server URL with /wd/hub, then please start Appium also with ‘--base-path=/wd/hub’

Or take out /wd/hub from the appium server URL.


